# Reduce the Spacing between vertically aligned input ranges

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

I want to create a simple equalizer gui using html and css and my maybe some JS. My problem is how can I edit the spacing between before and after the vertical input range? As you can see when aligning multiple sliders they take up too much space. How to deal with this?? For the html part I put each individual input element in a div so that I can align them next to each other using 'inline-block' , as you will in the code pasted below

```css
input.vertical {
                -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
                writing-mode: bt-lr;
            }
            .aligned {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .block{
                display: block;
            }
            input[type=range]{
                padding-left: 0px;
                padding-right: 0px;
            }
```

```html
<div class="aligned">
            <p>Gain</p>
            <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
        </div>
        <div class="aligned">
            <p>Gain</p>
            <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
        </div>
        <div class="aligned">
            <form>
                <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A"></label>
                <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A"></label>
                <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A"></label>
                <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A"></label>
                <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A"></label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="SF-container">
            <div class="aligned" style="padding-right: 0px; margin-left:0px; display: inline-block;">
                <p>Subsonic Filter</p>
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <input  type="range" id="fader" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="5" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about specifying a width?

```
 input.vertical {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    width: 30px;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/ORVbRp

Comment: LOL.. I was just about to try that and it seems to work perfectly. I wonder if there are some frameworks that supports building these type interfaces ?